When is the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) Particularly Useful?
I've often used the Mean Absolute Deviation, but I rarely hear of the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD). It seems that for some distributions with undefined means, it could come in handy. However, I'm struggling to see the broader interest in it. Could statisticians provide some intuition or visualizations on when MAD would be particularly useful?

The acronym $MAD$ is frequently used for Mean Absolute Deviation, though some writers prefer $AAD$ (for "Average Absolute Deviation").  In any case, I would avoid it here.

As to the question, it certainly comes up.  It is quite resistant to outliers which makes it attractive in cases where you might not trust extreme observations.  And, as you say, it is very handy to have a measure you can use when the underlying distribution lacks a mean.
